# Day specific hyperlink href change

Tags: jquery, html

I have a group of hyperlinks all linking to other pages and/or sites, each link has a class, starting at 1 and increasing incrementally, I only want the links from class '1' up to the present day to be active, yet the link itself to remain visible.

```
<div>
    <a href="http://google.com" class="link 1">LINK 1</a>
    <a href="http://google.com" class="link 2">LINK 2</a>
    <a href="http://google.com" class="link 3">LINK 3</a>
    <a href="http://google.com" class="link 4">LINK 4</a>
</div>
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
var d = new Date(),
    day = d.getDate(),
    number = $('a.link').attr("class").match(/\d+/);

if (number > day) {
    $("a.link").attr("href", "#")
} else {}
```

I'm trying to change the href rather than disable the link so that people won't be able to see the address from viewing the page source code.

Comment: Someone would be able to still see a link if they view the page source.

Comment: if the href is changed to '#', how would they be able to see the link?

Comment: Because JS isn't run when you view source

Comment: @TimWilkinson right click > view source. You're amending the DOM after load, not the source of the page which was downloaded to the browser. If you don't want people to see the successive days, you need to do this server-side.

Comment: +1 If visibility of the links is a concern, you'll have to implement this server side. People could also fool the site into showing links that shouldn't be active by changing the time on their computer. This is because web browsers just use the user's system time.

Comment: i will have a play, but its for an advent calendar style thing im building for a mate, so if people want to find the links they can, its more just for the everyday user so they cant jump ahead and ruin the 'fun' of finding out what each day is!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Much easier to use `data-*` attributes rather than trying to regex the number out of the `class` attribute:

```
<div>
    <a href="http://google.com" class="link" data-day="1">LINK 1</a>
    <a href="http://google.com" class="link" data-day="2">LINK 2</a>
    <a href="http://google.com" class="link" data-day="3">LINK 3</a>
    <a href="http://google.com" class="link" data-day="4">LINK 4</a>
</div>
```

Then you can just use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-functionindex):

```
$('a.link').filter(function(){
    return parseInt($(this).data('day'),10) > 2 // Use your day logic in place of the hardcoded "2"!
}).attr('href','#');
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T2sNF/1/

Comment: `+1` because it would work, but this still won't result in his idea of people not being able to view a link when viewing page source.

Comment: @ahren - oh I know that, Im just answering the question of how to change the href attribute.

Comment: Nice, elegant solution.

Comment: Ah also, as another note, you don't need to use `parseInt()` because `.data()` will typecast for you `=)`

Comment: Good to know, but I think I would still prefer to be explicit.